# How to use props with styled-components in switch statement

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, styled-components

So I was wondering if it is possible to use props in a switch statements in styled components. For example, let's say I have a prop `color` and a `type`, I.e:

```
let HeaderCustomizations = { type: String, color: String }
```

And the following switch statement:

```
const headerStyle = props => {
    switch (props.type) {
        case "underline":
            return `
                padding-bottom: 2px;
                border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(134, 38, 60);
            `;
        case "borderBottom":
            return `
                width: 100%;
                // Why doesn't this work? it does not get rendered properly.
                border-bottom: 2px solid ${props => props.color};
        `;
    }
}
```

I use this as follows:

```
export const HeaderStyling = styled('div', HeaderCustomizations)`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    ${(props) => headerStyle(props)}
`;
```

In the switch statement I like to use the color prop, I.e:

```
border-bottom: 2px solid ${props => props.color};
```

But that does not seem to work. I'm quite new to styled components so I might me missing something obvious...

Anyway, would love to know how I can use props in a switch statement with styled components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't working because you're setting the border color to a function, not a value. If you were to expand the case where props.type is borderBottom, you'd get:

```js
export const HeaderStyling = styled('div', HeaderCustomizations)`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    ${(props) => `
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 2px solid ${props => props.color};
    `}
`;
```

The solution is simply to change `border-bottom: 2px solid ${props => props.color};` to `border-bottom: 2px solid ${props.color};`

Comment: Well, that was easy. Cheers mate :)